# Python RegEx nested search and replace

Tags: python, regex, replace

I need to to a RegEx search and replace of all commas found inside of quote blocks.
i.e.

```
"thing1,blah","thing2,blah","thing3,blah",thing4
```

needs to become

```
"thing1\,blah","thing2\,blah","thing3\,blah",thing4
```

my code:

```
inFile  = open(inFileName,'r')
inFileRl = inFile.readlines()
inFile.close()

p = re.compile(r'["]([^"]*)["]')
for line in inFileRl:
    pg = p.search(line)
    # found comment block
    if pg:
        q  = re.compile(r'[^\\],')
        # found comma within comment block
        qg = q.search(pg.group(0))
        if qg:
            # Here I want to reconstitute the line and print it with the replaced text
            #print re.sub(r'([^\\])\,',r'\1\,',pg.group(0))
```

I need to filter only the columns I want based on a RegEx, filter further,
then do the RegEx replace, then reconstitute the line back.

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: not really an answer but before you reimplement one, maybe you could be better served by a CSV parser? That seems the format you are dealing with.

Comment: I'm actually looking to get the data ready for my custom CSV parser csv.register_dialect(
   'escapedExcel'                   ,
   delimiter        = ','           ,
   skipinitialspace = 0             ,
   doublequote      = 1             ,
   quoting          = csv.QUOTE_ALL ,
   quotechar        = '"'           ,
   lineterminator   = '\r\n'        ,
   escapechar       = '\\'          )

Comment: I see, then I believe you want to use the methods `span` and `start` of the match object to get at the stuff that was around it and recompose your line. But I am not sure why a single call to sub after the "selecting" loop would not be ok.

Comment: @Dragos Toader: Why would you want to replace commas inside quotes?  `csv.reader` has no problems with commas inside quotes.

Comment: Adding backslashes just means yet another mechanism for your parser to cope with. Now you will need to backslash all backslashes, too. The proper fix is to teach your CSV parser to ignore commas inside double quotes, or use an existing CSV parser which does.

Comment: I have a csv.reader wrapper that gave me some errors -- so I erroneously thought that csv.reader itself was not able to read internal quoted commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `csv` module is perfect for parsing data like this as `csv.reader` in the default dialect ignores quoted commas.  `csv.writer` reinserts the quotes due to the presence of commas.  I used `StringIO` to give a file like interface to a string.

```
import csv
import StringIO

s = '''"thing1,blah","thing2,blah","thing3,blah"
"thing4,blah","thing5,blah","thing6,blah"'''
source = StringIO.StringIO(s)
dest = StringIO.StringIO()
rdr = csv.reader(source)
wtr = csv.writer(dest)
for row in rdr:
    wtr.writerow([item.replace('\\,',',').replace(',','\\,') for item in row])
print dest.getvalue()
```

result:

```
"thing1\,blah","thing2\,blah","thing3\,blah"
"thing4\,blah","thing5\,blah","thing6\,blah"
```

Comment: +1 But you need to write ``item.replace('\\,',',').replace(',','\\,')`` , otherwise **"thing3\,blah "** is replaced with **"thing3\\,blah "**

Answer (score 1):

General Edit

There was

```
"thing1\\,blah","thing2\\,blah","thing3\\,blah",thing4
```

in the question, and now it is not there anymore.

Moreover, I hadn't remarked `r'[^\\],'`.

So, I completely rewrite my answer.

```
"thing1,blah","thing2,blah","thing3,blah",thing4
```

and

```
"thing1\,blah","thing2\,blah","thing3\,blah",thing4
```

being displays of strings (I suppose)

```
import re


ss = '"thing1,blah","thing2,blah","thing3\,blah",thing4 '

regx = re.compile('"[^"]*"')

def repl(mat, ri = re.compile('(?<!\\\\),') ):
    return ri.sub('\\\\',mat.group())

print ss
print repr(ss)
print
print      regx.sub(repl, ss)
print repr(regx.sub(repl, ss))
```

result

```
"thing1,blah","thing2,blah","thing3\,blah",thing4 
'"thing1,blah","thing2,blah","thing3\\,blah",thing4 '

"thing1\blah","thing2\blah","thing3\,blah",thing4 
'"thing1\\blah","thing2\\blah","thing3\\,blah",thing4 '
```

Comment: This answer has been upvoted. I would like to know why. I'm also perplexed by the fact that my rep is then diminished of 1 and not 2 points !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex.

```
>>> re.sub('(?<!"),(?!")', r"\\,", 
                     '"thing1,blah","thing2,blah","thing3,blah",thing4')
#Gives "thing1\,blah","thing2\,blah","thing3\,blah",thing4
```

The logic behind this is to substitute a `,` with `\,` if it is not immediately both preceded and followed by a `"`

Comment: Your solution is better than mine. You just need to write the pattern ``'([^"]+) *, *([^"]+)'`` or even ``'([^"]+)[\t ]*,[\t ]*([^"]+)'`` in case a comma is between blanks

Comment: Added the checks you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: How does this work with strings with two commas between the quotes?  `"thing1,blah,moreblah"`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yes, it does not work in that case. Both lookahead and lookbehind have to be used in that scenario. I will see if i can make those changes.

Comment: How about `re.sub('".+?"', lambda m: m.group(0).replace(',','\\,'), '"th,ing1,blah","thing2,""blah""","thing3,blah",thing4')`?

Comment: I made the required changes. Even the one you specified works like a charm. Thanks for pointing out the error!

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski By Jove , I didn't think to that ! Moreover, with your code, Narendra, ``"thing3\,blah"`` is transformed into ``"thing3\\,blah"`` instead of remaining untouched. Alas, lookahead and lookbehind assertions can't help because ``r"\1\\,\2"`` adds an antislash before a UNIQUE comma (the last one between " " because ``[^"]+`` is greedy) and the other commas remain out of care. I don't see any possibility to improve your pattern with lookbehind and looahead assertions. Sorry , I remove my upvote on this answer. But I put an upvote on another answer of you (regex for anagram)

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski Your replacement transforms ``"thing3\,blah"`` into ``"thing3\\,blah"`` but the OP doesn't want already present slashes to be doubled; see ``r'[^\\],'`` in his code

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an iterative solution using several regex functions:
finditer(), findall(), group(), start() and end()
There's a way to turn all this into a recursive function that calls itself.
Any takers?

```
outfile  = open(outfileName,'w')

p = re.compile(r'["]([^"]*)["]')
q = re.compile(r'([^\\])(,)')
for line in outfileRl:
    pg = p.finditer(line)
    pglen = len(p.findall(line))

    if pglen > 0:
        mpgstart = 0;
        mpgend   = 0;

        for i,mpg in enumerate(pg):
            if i == 0:
                outfile.write(line[:mpg.start()])

            qg    = q.finditer(mpg.group(0))
            qglen = len(q.findall(mpg.group(0)))

            if i > 0 and i < pglen:
                outfile.write(line[mpgend:mpg.start()])

            if qglen > 0:
                for j,mqg in enumerate(qg):
                    if j == 0:
                        outfile.write( mpg.group(0)[:mqg.start()]    )

                    outfile.write( re.sub(r'([^\\])(,)',r'\1\\\2',mqg.group(0)) )

                    if j == (qglen-1):
                        outfile.write( mpg.group(0)[mqg.end():]      )
            else:
                outfile.write(mpg.group(0))

            if i == (pglen-1):
                outfile.write(line[mpg.end():])

            mpgstart = mpg.start()
            mpgend   = mpg.end()
    else:
        outfile.write(line)

outfile.close()
```

Comment: Your code is incredibly tortuous: you are using regexes to do just a tiny part of what the regexes are for, in order to obtain elements of string on which you perform treatments thanks to string methods that are precisely what is done with regexes. By the way, you didn't remarked that your code gives a false result for **"thing3,blah"** that is transformed into **"thingx\x03,blah"** , I don't know how.

Comment: Also, by the way, did you, at any moment, remarked that there were answers and debates concerning the question you precisely put to obtain answers ? You doesn't do the slightestt allusion to other answers that we hoped helpful. Instead of that, you show a code without any interest, as if you haven't read the answers. I find this a little unfair.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into str.replace()?

> str.replace(old, new[, count])
>       Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old
>   replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the
>   first count occurrences are replaced.

[here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) is some documentation

hope this helps